# Confused about Having COUNT() = 0

Tags: mysql, database

I want to select rows with using inner join to another table.

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID), t3.act, t3.dj_id, t1.ID, 
  t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date, t1.genre, 
  t1.plink, t1.featana, t1.promo_aktif 
FROM `release` t1 
INNER JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID 
WHERE t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active' 
 AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id' 
HAVING COUNT(t3.ID) = 0 
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

In this query, result is empty. it selects 0 rows. but i am sure there are rows with this conditions.

query needs to select rows in `t1` when there is no record found in `t3`

where am i wrong in this query ?

thanks

EDIT

correct code is

```
SELECT t3.act, t3.dj_id, t1.ID, 
  t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date, t1.genre, 
  t1.plink, t1.featana, t1.promo_aktif 
FROM `release` t1 
LEFT JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id' 
WHERE t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active'
AND t3.release_id is null
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Comment: `query needs to select rows in t1 when there is no record found in t3` --- than is not what `INNER JOIN` supposed to do.

Comment: How can you select t3.act when t3 returns no rows?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and learn to use the space bar after commas. It makes it much easier to tell which column you're using (I'm referring, of course, to using `t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date` instead of `t1.name,t1.label_id,t1.date`. The first is much more readable when you need to go back later to add or remove a column, and makes it *much* easier for others who have to read it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct code is

```
SELECT t3.act, t3.dj_id, t1.ID, 
  t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date, t1.genre, 
  t1.plink, t1.featana, t1.promo_aktif 
FROM `release` t1 
LEFT JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id' 
WHERE t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active'
AND t3.release_id is null
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT t3.act, t3.dj_id, t1.ID, 
  t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date, t1.genre, 
  t1.plink, t1.featana, t1.promo_aktif 
FROM `release` t1 
LEFT JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID 
WHERE t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active'
    AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id' 
            AND t3.release_id is null
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Without knowing your code, I don't trust this condition: `t3.dj_id = '$id'`

Comment: Then it is just a matter of your filters. There MUST be something wrong in your code: `t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active' AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id'`. By "wrong" I mean that it is filtering more than it should. Remove all those filters and add them progressively to find out. Pay particular attention to `t3.dj_id = '$id'`

Comment: when i try "is not null" it shows all the records that also found in t3 but if i use "is null" it doesnt show the records that not found in t3 ?

Comment: IS NULL will show you only those records that are not in the t3. IS NOT NULL will show you only those records thare are present in t3

Comment: yes thats right and thats what i am sayin, even though it shows records that are present in t3 when i use IS NOT NULL, it comes with empty result when i use IS NULL. there should be some problem here.

Comment: Then, there are no records present in t1 and absent in t3 `THAT FULFILL THE OTHER CONDITIONS YOU SET` (see my previous comments)

Comment: ok found the fix. t3.dj_id and t3.act filter must be in JOIN part. like this -> LEFT JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID AND t3.act = 'hide' AND t3.dj_id = '$id. so please feel my pain too...

Answer (score 0):

This should give your desired result:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
  t1.name, t1.label_id, t1.date, t1.genre, 
  t1.plink, t1.featana, t1.promo_aktif 
FROM `release` t1 
LEFT JOIN `acts` t3 ON t3.release_id = t1.ID 
WHERE t1.ID IN ($lst) AND t1.promo_aktif = 'Active' 
 AND t3.release_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```